# No Bluetooth found in HP Probook

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ sudo lsmod | grep blue
bluetooth             548864  10 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth

$ sudo apt-get install bluetooth
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bluetooth is already the newest version (5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 80 not upgraded.
```

I have tried above things. I have also downloaded blueman. But nothing worked. So I deleted it. My laptop is HP Probook. I have downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 very recently. Initially it was working. But after some updates it stopped working.

Comment: You added some PPA. Most likely packages from there broke things.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   29.392957] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   29.392960] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   29.392963] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   29.392968] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   29.467072] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
[   56.209141] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   56.209143] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   56.209147] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

Comment: so i thik there is no harware problem. Drivers are also updated. Still bluetooth is not working

Comment: So how to rectify PPA packages?